How to convert a recursive union type to a union at the top level
Let's say I have this type:
type someUnionType = [1 | 2 | 3,"Some value"] | [4,"Another value"];

And I want to get this type:
type anotherUnionType = [1,"Some value"] | [2,"Some value"] | [3,"Some value"] | [4,"Another value"];

I have tried this:
type isAUnionAtTopLevel<T, U = T> = U extends any ? [T] extends [U[any]] ? true : false : false;
type convertToFlat<value> = value extends any ? true extends isAUnionAtTopLevel<(infer out extends value)> ? out : never : never;
type someUnionType = [1 | 2 | 3,"Some value"] | [4,"Another value"];
type anotherUnionType = convertToFlat<someUnionType>;

But anotherUnionType just gets set to never.
I was expecting anotherUnionType to be set to [1,"Some value"] | [2,"Some value"] | [3,"Some value"] | [4,"Another value"].

Given the OP's question in a comment under an answer how to make it universal and support any array length one could apply recursion:
type TopLevel<T> = T extends [infer A, ...infer B] ?  A extends any ? B extends [any, ...any[]] ? [A, ...TopLevel<B>] : [A]: never : never ;// used to create invidual types 
type someUnionType = [1 | 2 | 3, "Some value"] | [4, "Another value", 'Good' | 'Bad']; // original union
type anotherUnionType = TopLevel<someUnionType>; // flatten the union

Playground

type TopLevel<T> = T extends [infer A, infer B] ? A extends any ? [A, B] : never : never; // used to create invidual types 
type someUnionType = [1 | 2 | 3, "Some value"] | [4, "Another value"]; // original union
type anotherUnionType = TopLevel<someUnionType>; // flatten the union

Test cases:
const test1: anotherUnionType = [1, "Some value"];  // PASSED
const test2: anotherUnionType = [4, "Another value"]; // PASSED

const test3: anotherUnionType = [5, "Some value"];  // ERROR
const test4: anotherUnionType = [1, "Wrong value"]; // ERROR


Is there any way to make this more universal? Ex: works on arrays longer than two elements

upvoting since it gave me the start to work with
